# ElasticSearch | How to search for nested objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a search query that returns all documents where a participant is both `director` and `owner`. 
Problem is that this data is spread across multiple nested objects.

Please consider the following two documents:

```
{
      name: 'Facebook Inc.'
      participants: [
         {
           name: 'Mark Zuckerberg',
           roles: [
             {
               type: 'founder',
             },
             {
               type: 'owner',
             },
             {
               type: 'director',
             },

            ]
         }
      ] 
    },
    {
      name: 'Alphabet Inc.'
      participants: [
         {
           name: 'Larry Page',
           roles: [
             {
               type: 'founder',
             },
             {
               type: 'owner',
             }
            ]
         },
         {
           name: 'Sundar Pichai',
           roles: [
             {
               type: 'director',
             }
            ]
         },

      ] 
    }
```

Indexed the following way:

```
{
  index: 'companies',
  body: {
    mappings: {
      company: {
        properties: {
           name: {type: 'text'},
           participants: {
             type: 'nested',
             properties: {
               name: {type: 'text'},
               roles: {
                 type: 'nested',
                 properties: {
                   type: {type: 'text'}
                 }
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:** How can I create a search query that returns all documents where a `participant` is both `director` and `founder`?

Expected result is of course the Facebook example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "nested" : {
      "path" : "participants",
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "nested" : {
                "path" : "participants.roles",
                "query" : {
                    "match" : { "participants.roles.type": "founder" }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested" : {
                "path" : "participants.roles",
                "query" : {
                    "match" : { "participants.roles.type": "director" }
                }
              }
            }
            ]
        }
      }      
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that the position of the bool query is important. Placing it inside the first nested query signals that it must be a participant that has both roles.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution does not work (the search query returns 0 hits). 
Deleting `{ "match" : { "participants.roles.type" : "director" } }` does return all companies that have a founder, but combined they return 0